# How To Fit ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) Model

Tags: probability-or-statistics, time-series

An ARMA(1,1) model is defined as the following

$X_{t}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}+\beta_{t-1}\epsilon_{t-1}$

where a GARCH(1,1) model is defined as

$\epsilon_{t} = z_{t}\sqrt{a_{0}+a_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}^{2} +b_{1}\sigma_{t-1}^{2}}=z_{t}\sigma_{t}$

Where $\epsilon_{t}$ is the error term.

Combining the ARMA(1,1) and GARCH(1,1) yields the ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) model

$X_{t}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}X_{t-1}+z_{t}\sqrt{a_{0}+a_{1} \epsilon_{t-1}^{2} +b_{1}\sigma_{t-1}^{2}}+\beta_{t-1}z_{t-1}\sqrt{a_{0}+a_{1} \epsilon_{t-2}^{2}+b_{1}\sigma_{t-2}^{2} }$

How would I fit the above model using either TimeSeriesModelFit or Estimated Process?

Thanks

Comment: Given that an ARMA-GARCH model is relatively specialized and available in R (which you clearly have access to given your other questions), why not just use `RLink` ?  Duplicating functionality that already has lots of necessary checks and warning messages in R, it seems a bit risky.  Maybe explaining why it's necessary for you to have a version in *Mathematica* would generate more interest.

Comment: Considering Mathematica already has native time series forecasting functionality I can't believe they can't fit variants of GARCH models. It is much easier debugging code written in one language than code written in two languages.  I also have a lot more experience in Mathematica than any other language, so unless there is an absolute need for me to go to another language, I prefer not to.

Comment: @JimB I take it that this question will not be answered because it cannot be done in Mathematica. Should I write to Wolfram to ask them to include this feature in future releases? It is silly to have time series functionality that doesn't include the full spectrum of GARCH models.

Comment: One can do just about anything in *Mathematica* and it is by far the most useful and amazing software I've ever used.  However, as a statistician, I find the statistical functionality (meaning functions that don't requiring writing everything from scratch) to still be lacking (after over 30 years of using *Mathematica*).  There are no mixed model (i.e., multiple random effects) functions and limited Bayesian functionality.  Those features are used by folks much more often than ARMA-GARCH models so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Comment: For statistics is R the best solution out there or is there something better? I'm interested in statistics for financial quants.

Comment: R will have the latest and greatest functionality.  But if you need more stability (code that you wrote today probably still working as is 10 years from now) or need to defend analyses in court, then you might want to consider SAS (specifically its PROC AUTOREG).  That last consideration about court defense is simply me thinking that there's likely much more QA that goes into SAS procedures as SAS needs to keep its paying customers.